# Intellij Webstorm и Jade форматирование скомпилированного HTML

Tags: jade, webstorm

Есть IDE Webstorm в которой я работаю с Jade файлами, которые после компиляции в HTML выдают такое форматирование кода:

[image: got: ide screenshot]

А мне нужно вот такое:
[image: expected: ide screenshot]

Может такое делать webstorm из коробки или нужно использовать сборщики типа gulp?

Comment: словами опишите в чём вы видете проблему с форматированием кода (что ожидается, что вместо этого получается). Старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос.

Comment: используйте бьютифаер после сборки

Comment: @Etki то есть эти задачи можно и нужно решать с помощью gulp например? А как быть со вложенностью кода в jade?

Comment: в комментарий не нужно информацию о вопросе добавлять. В сам вопрос описание проблемы поместите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Jade есть опция --pretty
`-P, --pretty compile      pretty html output`
Добавьте её как аргумент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]